# refresh div with jq_form_remote_tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Two pictures. Problem take a look down under.

[image]

[image]

I do have the following code in my template - thanks a lot again to j0k:

```
<div id="listdiv">
echo jq_form_remote_tag(array(
    'update' => 'listdiv',
    'url' => 'shoppinglist/update',
    'loading' => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
    'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
));
</form>
</div>
```

When I type "apple" in the empty field and submit the form (first picture), everything will be saved in the db correctly. The result ist picture two. But the new field doesn't show up. Any idea?

If I do a full refresh, tomato, apple and a new text field is showing up correctly!

I switched off all if-method-GET/POST statements in action.class.php. Does anybody have an idea?

### Update

action.class.php

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
$endkunde_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id');
$zustand_id = 1;

$list_id = 252;
$shopname_id = 1;
$shopname = 'shop 1';

// if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == sfRequest::GET) {
    $this->form = new YourListForm(array(), array('endkunde_id' => $endkunde_id, 'list_id' => $list_id));
    $this->form2 = new AddOnYourListForm(array('shopname' => $shopname), array('endkunde_id' => $endkunde_id, 'list_id' => $list_id, 'shopname_id' => $shopname_id));
//  }

}

public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request) {
$endkunde_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id');
$zustand_id = 1;

$list_id = 252;
$shopname_id = 1;
$shopname = 'shop 1';

    $this->addon_listForm = new AddOnYourListForm();
    $addonlist = array();

    $p = 'addon_list_id_';
    $q = (string) 252;
    $p .= $q;

    $this->addon_listForm->bind($request->getParameter($p));
    if ($this->addon_listForm->isValid()) {
        $formData = $this->addon_listForm->getValues();
        // $this->addon_listForm->save();
    }

    $this->form = new YourListForm(array(), array('list_id' => $list_id, 'endkunde_id' => $endkunde_id));
    $p = 'yourlist_';
    $q = (string) 252;
    $p .=$q;

    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($p));
    if ($this->form->isValid()) {
        $this->form->save();
        $this->form = new YourListForm(array(), array('list_id' => $list_id, 'endkunde_id' => $endkunde_id));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the relevant part of your actions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one solution:

Short explanation:

action.class.php:

```
executeIndex{
if (method = post) {
 //handle the data
}
//here my index code above without method GET!!
}
```